# How does Arduino(Sigfox) send informationto Mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, database, cpanel

i am a newbie in Javascript and i have a question regarding passing of information from Arduino all the way to a mobile application.

So first of all, in the mobile app that i will be creating will only consist of Javascript, html and css.

The things that i will be using:

-Arduino Device

-Sigfox add-on

-cPanel

-Mobile app

I will be creating an IOT device with arduino and a Sigfox add-on (Which passes a small byte of information to their Sigfox server) But the question is, how do i get sigfox to send to cPanel and how to get cPanel to send to mobile app?

*I do not need any code.. but just some guidance of how it works from getting Arduino device all the way to my javascript mobile app.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I documented a project that did what you needed.

In this project, I hooked up a button to my Arudino UNO. When the button is pressed, it will send a message through the Sigfox backend to my virtual server, and then finally as a notification to my mobile phone.

Take a look at it here, am happy to assist further should you require any assistance.

https://jacksonng.org/zoe-helper-sigfox-sos-device-part-1